# PWM created from 16-bit timer and 32-bit timer

Tags: pwm

I have a question that does the PWM created from 16-bit timer differ from one created from 32-bit timer.

Personally, I deem that they are the same, since by taking the fourier series of the PWM signal I see that the dc level of PWM signal solely depends on the duty cycle.

Thanks!

Comment: Ofcourse they differ in resolution. With 32bit timer you can fix your value more precisely than on 16bit timer.

Comment: At realistic PWM frequencies there will be no difference. Above 1 kHz PWM frequency you can't exceed 16 bit resolution unless your clock frequency is above 65 MHz (2^16 ticks per PWM sample).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-bit refers to the resolution you can achieve with the timer itself. 32 bit can achieve a higher resolution compared to its 16 bit counterpart. It means you can generate more accurate pwm signals with the 32 bit, but it will act exactly the same if you're using it at 16 bit resolution.

Comment: Higher resolution which comes with cost of frequency. At least, if same clock is used. In TI C2000 they allow like x bits on counter and another 3 bits to shift the edge within one clok cycle. This really is nice, because provides resolution with same frequency.

Comment: Yeah I was going to mention that it's linked with clock speed but wasn't sure if it's the same for all microcontrollers, the exact workings probably differ between devices.